#  series    Sum[(-1)^n/(x+n)]

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

I need the following sum ( in the sense of principal value):
$$\sum_{s=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{s}e^{-2\pi isy}}{x+s}$$

It is possible to show that
$$\sum_{s=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-2\pi isy}}{x+s}=\pi\frac{e^{\pi ix(2FractionalPart[y]-1)}}{\sin(\pi x)}$$

Hence the sum I need  is
$$f(y)=\sum_{s=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-2\pi is(y+0.5)}}{x+s}=\pi\frac{e^{\pi ix(2FractionalPart[y+0.5]-1)}}{\sin(\pi x)}$$
But now it is difficult to see that the function f is continuous   on $(0,1)$.
How to obtain expression without 0.5?

The second question is what are this series in both cases? 
Maybe I wrong, but it seems that it is not Fourier series of $\pi\frac{e^{\pi ix(y-1)}}{\sin(\pi x)}$

Comment: Your manipulation with pretty divergent series is shocking, "How to obtain expression without 0.5?" is absolutely unclear.

Comment: why do you think that this series are divergent? The summation is in the sense of principle value.  I though that this series might be known. At least I saw the formula without $-1^s$ in the literature(Ehlich) 

Comment: When you provide a value for a divergent series, you need to tell the reader what summation method was used.  I believe this time you used a "principal value" such as $\lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{s=-N}^N$.  Is that right?

Comment: yes, thats right

Comment: Good.  Please say "principal value" or whatever method was used when you give a "value" for a divergent series in the mathematics context.  In a physics context, these "technicalities" are often omitted.  But not here.


Comment: OK, at least you explain now how to understand your series, but even in this case your derivation is vague and the question unclear. (Have you checked http://mathoverflow.net/questions/27592/ ?) It's a matter of respect to work on your question before putting it on MO. To me your question sounds like a draft for personal use, so I suggest you to put more effort for this post. 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is in a typical complex analysis text
$$
\frac{1}{x} + \sum_{s = 1}^{\infty}\left( \frac{1}{x + s} + \frac{1}{x - s}\right) = \pi \cot (\pi x)
$$
When grouped this way, it converges...

Maple says
$$
\frac{1}{x} + \sum_{s = 1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{\operatorname{e} ^{(-2 i\pi s y)}}{x + s} + \frac{\operatorname{e} ^{2 i \pi s y}}{x - s}\right) = 
-\frac{1 - LerchPhi \biggl(\frac{1}{\operatorname{e} ^{2 i \pi y}},1,x\biggr) x + LerchPhi \bigl(\operatorname{e} ^{2 i \pi y},1,-x\bigr) x}{x}
$$
and numerically this seems to agree with what you said.

So your formula looks correct.  Why do you say it is not continuous?  The complex exponential has period $2\pi i$.

Comment: yes, I know this.So I can also write 

 $$\sum_{s=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(x+s)}=\pi\cot[\pi x](principle value)$$ right? 
Also 
$$\sum_{s=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{s}}{(x+s)}=\frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi x)}(principal value)$$
 But I don't know how to treat exponentials 

Comment: It is continuous, but for my further  computation I need to consider two cases 
{y}>0.5 and {y}< 0.5  where {}-denotes fractional part.And I don't see how to join them.  I work on (0,1). So, I was wondering maybe there is another representation for this sum. 

Comment: Notation: $P.V.\sum_{s=-\infty}^{\infty}(\ldots)$ denotes the principal value sum.