# Reduction of size of orthogonal matrices.

Tags: reference-request, linear-algebra

While experimenting with orthogonal vectors I've noticed the 
following transformation: If 
$$
    A = \begin{bmatrix}z & r \cr
                       c & B\end{bmatrix}
$$
is orthogonal, $z$ and $B$ square, and $I+z$ invertible, then the
smaller matrix
$$
    A_1 = B-c(I+z)^{-1}r
$$
is also orthogonal, it is not hard to show.  I would like to know:

1. Reference request: Is this a known transformation? It must be, but I don't
   see it in books so far.
2. For the case where $z$ is $1\times1$, it is not hard to show that
   $\frac{1}{1+z}cr$ is bounded as $z$ tends to $-1$. But in fact,
   setting $A_1 = B$ in the case where $z=-1$,
   several numerical examples suggest that the mapping $O(n)\to O(n-1)$,
   $A\to A_1$, might even be continuous. It preserves inverses, but is
   not a homomorphism.
   The case $O(2)\to O(1)$ is constant on the two components and is continuous.
   So: is the mapping $O(n)\to O(n-1)$,
   $A\to A_1$, continuous?
3. Entirely speculative: if it is continuous, is $O(n)\to O(n-1)$ a bundle?
   At least the inverse image of each point seems to be $S^{n-1}$: 
   Given $A_1\in O(n-1)$ and any unit $1\times n$ row vector $[z\ r]$
   the matrix
   $$
          A = \begin{bmatrix} z & r \cr
                             -A_1r^T & A_1(I-\frac{1}{1+z}r^Tr) \end{bmatrix}
         \quad {\rm or,\ if\  }
         z=-1, \ \ 
         A = \begin{bmatrix} -1 & 0 \cr
                              0 & A_1 \end{bmatrix},
     $$
   is in $O(n)$ and maps to $A_1$.

Comment: Warning: this may be unrelated.  I was excited by some recent (2012) results by Brent, Osborn, et. al. on arXiv regarding determinants of binary matrices.  They used a nice result of someone whose name is like Szollozi on unitary matrices.  Your question suggested this last result to me, which I think goes back to Jacobi.  If I find the link before someone else does, I will post it.  Gerhard "Ask Me Not About Smartphones" Paseman, 2012.11.14

Comment: Certainly $O(3)$ is not a bundle over $O(2)$, just for $\pi_1$ reasons. 

Comment: Just a note: your $\det A = \pm 1,$ and $\det A \det B = \det z.$ See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/3134/whats-your-favorite-equation-formula-identity-or-inequality/17139#17139  

Comment: reminds me of Schur complement, somehow.http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement

Comment: @DimaPasechnik: if you define the space $P(n)=I+O(n)$, this means that $P(n)$ is closed by Schur complementation (exactly like positive semidefinite matrices, or M-matrices --- two other classes of matrices for which all the eigenvalues lie in the right half-plane). This seems an interesting statement; it is new to me.

Comment: The above somehow reminds me of orthogonal deflation ...