# Equality of the determinants of certain submatrices of an orthogonal matrix

Tags: riemannian-geometry

Is the determinant of any submatrix of an ORTHOGONAL matrix extracted from the intersection of $k$ row and $k$ columns equal to that of the $(n-k)(n-k)$ submatrix remaining after deletion of these rows and columns (up to a sign)?! this is something I arrived at in trials to show that the Hodge Star operator’s definition does not depend on the choice of an orthonormal basis of $T*_xM$, $M$ a Reimannian manifold.

Comment: Yes, and you arrived at this exactly the way I did. I mentioned it to other differential geometry people, it was unfamiliar to all. But I also showed it to a matrix expert in the late 1980's, he showed me a one-line proof, typeset in my answer below. Note that column permutations and row permutations allow you to take a standard block pattern without loss of generality. 

Answer (score 8):

Given a square matrix $M \in SO_n$ decomposed as illustrated  with square blocks $A,D$ and rectangular blocks $B,C,$

$$M  = \left( \begin{array}{cc} 
A & B \\\  
 C & D 
 \end{array} \right) ,$$

then   $\det A = \det D.$

What this says is that, in Riemannian geometry with an orientable manifold, the Hodge star operator is an isometry, a fact that has relevance for Poincare duality.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodge_duality

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_duality

But the proof is a single line:

$$ \left( \begin{array}{cc}  A & B \\\  0 & I  \end{array} \right) 
\left( \begin{array}{cc}  A^t & C^t \\\ B^t & D^t  \end{array} \right)   = 
\left( \begin{array}{cc}  I & 0 \\\  B^t & D^t  \end{array} \right). $$

Comment: I first put this at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/3134/whats-your-favorite-equation-formula-identity-or-inequality/17139#17139 in March 2010. So sue me. 

Comment: Can anything be said about the invertibility of the block C?

Answer (score 2):

Let $M\in{\bf GL}_n(k)$ be written blockwise
$$M=\begin{pmatrix} A & B \\\\ C & D \end{pmatrix},$$
with $A$ a square, invertible, submatrix. The Sherman-Morrison formula says that
$$\det M=\det A\cdot\det(D-CA^{-1}B).$$
On the other hand, it can be shown that
$$M^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix} \cdot & \cdot \\\\ \cdot & (D-CA^{-1}B)^{-1} \end{pmatrix}.$$
We therefore have
$$\det M\cdot\det(D-CA^{-1}B)^{-1}=\det A.$$
When $M$ is orthogonal, one has $\det M=\pm1$, and the previous formula is exactly what you guessed.

Comment: Recent work (2012) of Richard Brent and Judy-ann Osborn on determinants of binary matrices  uses a similar (if not
identical) observation by F. Szollozi to get better bounds
on such determinants.  Gerhard "Ask Me About Binary
Matrices" Paseman, 2013.06.23

Comment: Denis, in this special case there is a one line proof. I cannot recall the name of the guy who found it for me, he was a matrix (and other) expert at U.C. San Diego in the late 1980's. 