# Hodge duality and the determinant of the product of two matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, determinants, exterior-algebra

I stumbled onto the following identity, and I would like to know: Is it known by some name and are there some references I might cite (or is it actually too trivial to be mentioned anywhere)? Are there any slick proofs that come to mind (for example something like Will Jagy's in [this somehow related question](https://mathoverflow.net/a/134554/))? (I may need to explain this to some folks who are not familiar with the exterior algebra.)

Let $V$ be a $n$-dimensional inner product space and let $A$ be the $k\times n$ matrix whose rows are the $n$-dimensional vectors $a_1,\dots,a_k\subset V$ and let $B$ be the $n\times k$ matrix whose columns are the $n$-dimensional vectors $b_1,\dots,b_k\subset V$.

Furthermore suppose for simplicity that $a_1,\dots,a_k$ are orthonormal in $V$ and that $a_1,\dots,a_k,\tilde{a}_{k+1},\dots,\tilde{a}_n$ form an orthonormal basis for $V$.

> **Proposition:** $\det(AB)=\det(M)$ where $M$ is the $n\times n$ matrix whose first $k$ columns are $b_1,\dots,b_k$ and whose last $n-k$ columns are $\tilde{a}_{k+1},\dots,\tilde{a}_n$.

Proof: Recall that the inner product on $V$ induces [an inner product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra#Inner_product) on $\Lambda^kV$ so that $\det(AB)=\langle a_1\wedge\cdots\wedge a_k,b_1\wedge\cdots\wedge b_k\rangle$.  Then, by the [definition of the Hodge star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodge_dual#Formal_definition_of_the_Hodge_star_of_k-vectors), $\det(AB)\omega=b_1\wedge\cdots\wedge b_k\wedge \star(a_1\wedge\cdots\wedge a_k)$, where $\omega\subset\Lambda^nV$ is the unit $n$-vector (n.b. $\omega=a_1\wedge\cdots\wedge\tilde{a}_n$, it is not simply a unit $n$-dimensional vector).  But then $\star(a_1\wedge\cdots\wedge a_k)=\tilde{a}_{k+1}\wedge\cdots\wedge\tilde{a}_n$, so that $\det(AB)\omega=b_1\wedge\cdots\wedge b_k\wedge \tilde{a}_{k+1}\wedge\cdots\wedge\tilde{a}_n$, which yields the proposition as desired.

Comment: WLOG suppose $a_i$ are coordinate vectors. Then the result reduces to a trivial computation.

Comment: Isn't your $M $ underdefined?

Comment: @darijgrinberg I see that the $\tilde{a}$'s are not unique, but I think that it doesn't matter (though I should have written "positively oriented orthonormal basis" when introducing them). I am probably missing the thrust of your comment.

Comment: Oh, I've just reread the proposition, and it does make sense now.

Comment: I'd say that the Proposition is a consequence of the Cauchy-Binet formula, the Laplace expansion along the first $n-k$ columns of $M$, and the result (classical?) that a minor of an invertible matrix equals the complementary minor of its inverse (here applied to the matrix with columns $a_1, \ldots, a_k, \widetilde{a}_{k+1}, \ldots, \widetilde{a}_n$, whose inverse is its own transpose). But your proof appears to be a lot simpler...