# The proof of the invertibility of $\Big( \sin\frac{8kl\pi}{2n+1} \Big)_{k,l=1}^\frac{n}{2}$

Tags: linear-algebra, fourier-transform, matrix-theory, numerical-linear-algebra, eigenvector

Suppose  that $n$ is even. Any suggestion/appraoch  to prove that $S=\Big( \sin\frac{8kl\pi}{2n+1} \Big)_{k,l=1}^\frac{n}{2}$ is invertible?

Comment: It is a submatrix of the discrete Sine transform of type V. The invertibility of this submatrix will lead me to analyze this type of DST.

Comment: Yes, and I edited in the question.

Comment: You might add to the question your reason for being interested in this, and (if any) your attempts to find whether it is already well-known.

Answer (score 3):

[The DST-I matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_sine_transform#DST-I) of size $4N$ is $\left ( \sin \frac{\pi k \ell}{4N+1} \right )_{k,\ell = 1}^{4N}$. Up to scale, it is orthogonal. Slightly changing notation, your matrix is $\left ( \sin \frac{8 \pi k \ell}{4N+1} \right )_{k,\ell = 1}^{N}$. By permuting rows and then columns of the DST-I matrix, orthogonality is preserved; by doing this suitably, your matrix can be regarded as a block of a 2x2 block which is itself a block of a 2x2 block. Applying [Equality of the determinants of certain submatrices of an orthogonal matrix](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/134545/) twice then yields the desired result.

Comment: Note that I am also using the Sherman-Morrison result in the MO link

Comment: Many thanks for your comments.  Actually, I could not get the result by this idea yet. As you mentioned (up to some permutations) we may first represent  DST-I=$\Big(\begin{array}{cc} A_{11} & A_{12} \\  A_{21} & A_{22}\end{array}\Big)$ where all submatrices/blocks $A_{ij}$s  are $2N\times 2N$ matrices and $A_{11}$ includes all entries $s_{i,j}$  of DST-I such that both $i,j$ are even. Up to here, one may check that $A_{11}$ is still invertible.

Comment: We may also assume that  $A_{11}=\Big(\begin{array}{cc}X & Y \\ Z & W\end{array}\Big)$ where $X$ is the matrix $S$ in the problem. I guess we may only conclude that det$X$=det$W$. So, please give some more details why det$X\neq0$.

Comment: If   diagonal entries of the matrix $W$ are all non-zero, it seems that det$X\neq0$, does not it?!

Comment: The Sherman-Morrison part implies nonzero determinant because the ambient matrix has nonzero determinant.

Comment: What is the ambient matrix here?

Comment: DST-I is the ambient matrix.

Comment: You are applying    twice of   the Sherman-Morrison.   In the first time, it is okay, but    why do you allow to apply  it for the second time? What is ambient matrix in the second time?

Comment: The first time, the ambient matrix is the $4N \times 4N$ DST-I matrix; the $2N \times 2N$ matrix obtained from this has nonzero determinant by Sherman-Morrison. The second time, the ambient matrix is the $2N \times 2N$ matrix just obtained; the $N \times N$ matrix you are interested in has nonzero determinant by S-M. Then you are done.

Comment: I am really following to get the result but could not yet. Do you address  "*Equality of the determinants of certain submatrices of an orthogonal matrix*" for  the version of S-M theorem that you are applying? If yes, I can not see the required assumption to get the desired result!  Please give some more clear explanation or let us know what version of S-M you are using.

Comment: The answer by Denis Serre points out that by S-M, $\det M = \det A \cdot \det(D-CA^{-1}B)$ where $M = \left ( \begin{smallmatrix} A & B \\ C & D \end{smallmatrix} \right )$. We are extracting an $A$ block two times, with the first $M$ as DST-I with rows and columns permuted, so that $\det M \ne 0$ both times, so $\det A \ne 0$ both times, hence each $A$ is invertible. The second $A$ is the matrix you want.

Comment: But I think the formula $\det M=  der A\cdot det(D-CA^{-1}B)$ holds if both $M$ and $A$ are invertible. When $M$ is considered as DST-I, one may check (some details are needed) $A$ is invertible as well. So one may apply S-M formula for the first step. But when we block-wise $A$ into four blocks, we are   no longer  sure concerning the invertibility of the first block.

Comment: After all, you can imagine the anti-diagonal matrix to check that S-M formula does not hold!